# Loading decimal number to "number" input doesn't appear as decimal

Tags: html, angularjs

I am using AngularJS in my project and i am trying to load data from the backend to a form in my frontend using data-ng-model.
I have encountered a problem while trying to load a decimal number to the "number" input. 
My input looks like that:

```
<input data-ng-model="offer.price" step="0.01" min="0.03" class="form-control" type="number" id="priceCPC" name="price" required="required" placeholder="$" value="{{offer.price}}">
```

For the record; the numbers i am trying to load to it are 0.07 and 1.3. For the 0.07 it shows nothing and for the 1.3 it shows only "1".
I am getting the number from the backend as a string, could that be a problem?

**update**

I am now getting an int value of the price from the backend but still have the same error.

Comment: have you tried putting in data type as decimal http://toodledo.github.io/ADE/

Comment: Are you sure that you are passing correct values to the form? I.E. `{{offer.price}}` is 1.3 and not 1? http://jsfiddle.net/78ejmm3a/1/

Comment: "I am now getting an int value of the price ", you should return decimal number form the backend!!